# Jest testing. React functional component and ForwardRef

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How to go deeper into ForwardRef in jest + enzyme? I Have functional component which renders something which depends on state (useState), but I can't test what is rendered and I can't check state and logic in functional component. I'm using `mount` from enzyme

**wrappper.debug():**

```
<BmPopper open={false} placement="bottom-start" anchorEl={{...}} transition={true} className="makeStyles-popper-1009">
    <ForwardRef(Popper) open={false} placement="bottom-start" anchorEl={{...}} transition={true} className="makeStyles-popper-1009" />
</BmPopper>
```

Comment: could you provide runnable sandbox? `mount()` returns expanded version for me, are you sure you don't use `shallow()` by accident?

Comment: @skyboyer yes. I'm sure